# Creating a Apache superset user through API

Tags: apache-superset

I want to create user through apache superset API if user already exist it should show message.

```
import requests
payload = { 'username': 'My user name',
 'password': 'my Password',
'provider': 'db'
}
base_url="http://0.0.0.0:8088"

login_url =f"{base_url}/api/v1/security/login"
login_response =requests.post(login_url,json=payload)
access_token = login_response.json()
print(access_token)
# header
header = {"Authorization":f"Bearer {access_token.get('access_token')}"}
base_url="http://0.0.0.0:8088"   # apache superset is running in my local system on port 8088
user_payload={
'first_name': "Cp",
               'last_name': "user",
               'username':"A",
               'email': "user.@gmail.com",
               'active': True,
               'conf_password': "user@1",
               'password': "user@1",
               "roles":["Dashboard View"]
}
users_url = f"{base_url}/users/add"
user_response= requests.get(users_url, headers=header)
print(user_response)
print(user_response.text)
user_response = user_response.json()
print(user_response)
```

I tried to create user through mentioned API, some time it gives 200 success message, but after checking in apache superset website i can not see created user details.

If i am using the wrong API endpoint or wrong methods to create user please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this is by installing the [***superset-api-client***](https://pypi.org/project/superset-api-client/) package with this command `pip install superset-api-client` and then change this script based on your needs:

```py
from superset_api_client import Superset
import requests

# Superset API configuration
superset_url = 'http://your-superset-url'
username = 'admin'
password = 'admin_password'

# User details
new_user = {
    'username': 'new_user',
    'firstname': 'New',
    'lastname': 'User',
    'email': 'new_user@example.com',
    'password': 'new_user_password',
}

# Initialize Superset API client
client = Superset(superset_url, username, password)

# Check if user exists
existing_user = client.get(f'/api/v1/user/?q={new_user["username"]}')

if existing_user:
    print(f"User '{new_user['username']}' already exists.")
else:
    # Create a new user
    response = client.post('/api/v1/user/', json=new_user)

    if response.status_code == requests.codes.created:
        print(f"User '{new_user['username']}' created successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to create user. Status code: {response.status_code}, Message: {response.text}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the endpoint `/api/v1/security/users/` which is not available by default.

I already answered a similar question about how to [Create or Update Roles in Apache Superset Programmatically](https://Create%20or%20Update%20Roles%20in%20Apache%20Superset%20Programmatically):

> An alternative to the previous answers would be to enable the FAB REST
> API in Superset. Apache Superset uses Flask App Builder (FAB), whose
> API is hidden by default.
>
> Setting [FAB's configuration variable](https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html) `FAB_ADD_SECURITY_API = True` in
> `superset_config.py` adds a CRUD REST API for users, roles,
> permissions, view_menus reachable under `/api/v1/security/`. [More on
> how to configure Apache Superset](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/configuring-superset).

Example: Add a new user

```bash
curl --request POST \
    --url http://localhost:8088/api/v1/security/users/ \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer token' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'X-CSRFToken: token' \
    --data '{"active": true,"email": "","first_name": "","last_name": "","password": "","roles": [1],"username": ""}'
```

Python:

```py
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8088/api/v1/security/users/"

payload = {
    "active": True,
    "email": "",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "password": "",
    "roles": [1],
    "username": ""
}
headers = {
    "X-CSRFToken": "",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer "
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```